# Python, Kivy, Buildozer: APK crashes with SymPy

Tags: android, python, kivy, sympy, buildozer

As the title says, I've made an .apk to run on my Android mobile. It runs perfectly on PC. As soon as I take out all SymPy commands, it runs on Android too. I've mentioned the "sympy" in the buildozer.spec file, and it's not giving any errors. But as soon, as the loading on my Android-screen is over, the App disappears.

Does anyone know, if I have to do more, than mentioning the sympy in the .specs file?

```
ADB-Logcat: "ImportError: No module named unittest"
```

I don't know, what "unittest" ist, and why it's trying to get imported.

**Solved: I found unittest.py (google: "inurl:unittest.py") and saved it inside the project folder.**

Comment: I think that's all that should be necessary for sympy. What's the output of `buildozer android logcat` (or otherwise calling `adb logcat`) when you run the app?

Comment: Well, `buildozer android logcat` is not about to find my mobile right now...?!

Comment: How must I mention sympy, if I just got that and kivy to import?

Comment: Ok. The adb logcat shows: "ImportError: No module named unittest". I never imported anything called "unittest". How to fix it?

Comment: My guess is that sympy tries to import unittest - you probably can see this in the traceback (can you paste it all here?). The ideal solution might be to create a sympy recipe for python-for-android that patches out this import, since it's almost certainly not necessary to run.

Comment: Actually I just grepped sympy and didn't see such a line. Still, can you paste the full related traceback?

Comment: I fixed that error by adding a file 'unittest.py'. But now: "module object has no attribute 'TestCase'" - is there a way, to get the original unittest (not unittest2) file, with all functions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I think it can still help.

This is because the unittest module is blacklisted, see blacklist.txt file in the .buildozer/ directory.

```
grep unittest .buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/*/blacklist.txt
```

So you can whitelist it by updating your buildozer.spec:

```
# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
android.whitelist = unittest/*
```