# Sympy module. Error in buildozer: no module named sympy.testing

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, buildozer

Hi I'm getting this error when I run my code: No module named 'sympy.testing'. I have added the module in buildozer.spec as sympy. Here there is the log: https://easyupload.io/0z0j52
Buildozer.spec: https://easyupload.io/6fscc0

Comment: Have you [seen this ticket](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/903) from buildozer ?

Comment: Or the following: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080615/python-kivy-buildozer-apk-crashes-with-sympy) ; [link2](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/2303) ; [kivy-users mailing list sympy-related problems](https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users/search?q=sympy) . A user claims [he found a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62182709/827519) (maybe the same problem you have).

Comment: I did it yesterday but the error is this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy.testing'. I attach the buildozer.spec file

Comment: I know nothing of buildozer or kivy myself. But the way to handle this would be to find a working `buildozer.spec` online, or to post the one you have in the `kivy-users` mailing list and ask other users there, or to [open an issue on github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues) if you come to the conclusion that you're following the project's documentation and you still get the errors.